# Can g++ warn when passing a negative literal as an unsigned parameter?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++, compiler-warnings

Consider:

```
unsigned foo(unsigned u) {
    return u;
}

int main() {
    foo(-1);
    return 0;
}
```

Here, the function `foo` is called with `u` equal to 4294967295 (or a similar large value.) If the programmer wasn't paying attention, this might be quite unexpected.

For instance, maybe you are implementing `pow` to raise your Polynomial class to a power. Since only positive powers are possible, you decide on the signature

```
Polynomial pow(const Polynomial& p, unsigned exp);
```

Then a careless programmer calls `pow(p, -1)` to get an inverse and, rather than a warning or error, it appears to work, but probably uses an extreme amount of memory and time to produce a totally wrong answer.

g++ 5.3.0, and gcc 5.3.0, compile this without complaint with `-Wall -Wextra`.

They will warn about it with the option `-Wsign-conversion`, but this warns about *every* conversion from `int` to `unsigned` and is rapidly too annoying (it warns every time you index into a vector with an `int`, `vec[i]`, for example.)

Can gcc warn just about passing a negative literal, or other negative compile-time constant, as an unsigned parameter?

Comment: Given that unsigned integer types implement arithmetic in Z/2^NumBit, warning about this does not make sense as -1 == 4294967295 in Z/2^32 (more precisely, they are representatives of the same equivalence class). If you don't want this kind of arithmetic, use signed types. Opinions of some experts: 
https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Interactive-Panel-Ask-Us-Anything 9:50, 42:40, 1:02:50

Comment: BTW, the irony is that the `pow` function takes floating point parameters, not integral.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21243076/c-how-to-block-negative-numbers-being-passed-as-argument-where-unsigned-is-exp

Comment: To make my first comment more concrete: Just use `Polynomial pow(const Polynomial& p, int exp);` and assert that `exp` is positive (or non-negative, whatever fits).

Comment: `pow()` has no problem with negative powers. The only restriction is that if the base is negative _and_ the exponent is negative, then the exponent must be an integer value.

Comment: @BaummitAugen: Yes, I agree that would be best in this situation.

Comment: @vacuumhead: Not for polynomials.

Comment: Detail: As post is tagged C, there are no _negative literals_ in C - just _string literals_ and _compound literals_.  There are _integer constants_ with a negative value.

Comment: @chux: Ah geez. By "literal" I mean _when I literally write down a value_ like 321 or 77ul or 0x3b or "Hello", as opposed to a "constant" which is a named variable whose value doesn't change. It would be nice if terminology for this was really consistent across languages.

Answer (score 0):

The -Wconversion will warn you of the implicit conversion in the passed argument.  Add -Werror if you want to treat the warning as an error.

Here is my test and its results.

Source code file temp.c:

```
unsigned foo(unsigned u) {
    return u;
}

int main() {
  foo(-1);
}
```

And the compilation,

```
$ gcc -o temp temp.c -Wconversion
temp.c: In function ‘main’:
temp.c:6:7: warning: negative integer implicitly converted to unsigned type [-Wsign-conversion]
   foo(-1);
       ^
```

If you change the argument to 1, and compile again, the warning will go away.

(Aside, it's a good idea to always use -Wall, as well).